# Cypress cannot run because this binary file does not have executable permissions

Tags: automation, cypress

I was trying to create a new project in cypress and I got the following strange error message.

Steps:

1. npm init -y
2. npm install cypress --save-dev

I then did `npx open cypres`s and I got the following message from my console

How do I fix this?

```
Cypress cannot run because this binary file does not have executable permissions here:

/Users/myName/Library/Caches/Cypress/7.5.0/Cypress.app/Contents/MacOS/Cypress

Reasons this may happen:

- node was installed as 'root' or with 'sudo'
- the cypress npm package as 'root' or with 'sudo'

Please check that you have the appropriate user permissions.

You can also try clearing the cache with 'cypress cache clear' and reinstalling.

----------

Platform: darwin (20.5.0)
Cypress Version: 7.5.0
```

Comment: Did you install npm with sudo ?

Comment: I can't remember I might have.  How could I check?

Comment: can you run `npm -v`?

Comment: version  number 7.12.1

Answer (score 1):

You can do two things:

1. Run the command `npm cypress cache clear` and then again install cypress `npm install cypress --save-dev` and check.
2. Or, install npm globally without sudo using the command `npm install -g`. Then create a new folder and then run `npm init`, `npm install cypress --save-dev` and `npx cypress open`.

Comment: Hi, it was installing fine and is stuck on `reifyNode:node_modules/lodash`

Comment: Remove npm first. run the command `npm uninstall -g`. if that doesn't work try with `sudo npm uninstall -g` and then try again.

Comment: I think it might be a node modules thing.  But  before I move forward I've raised the issue with cypress as I want their feedback too as I've never experienced this before.

Answer (score 1):

Do navigate to the cache directory by doing

```
cd /Users/myName/Library/Caches/
```

Here you have to delete Cypress directory completely by running the command

```
rm -rf Cypress
```

Now head over to your project directory and run the command

```
npx install cypress
```

Cypress will be installed in your system again. Next time you won't get any errors.

Answer (score 0):

So, I had a chat with the dev team at Cypress and got the following answer.  After reading the logs I had a feeling this might be the root cause.  So please check you have the most up to date version of Node.js

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are downloading and installing cypress manually using zip file, Make sure you download the correct version of cypress for right operating system using options

for example https://download.cypress.io/desktop/3.8.3**?platform=linux**

for more information refer to

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/advanced-installation#Run-binary